# MySQL Query with multiple WHEREs, some may be empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a query where a user can enter: first name, last name, nick name, grade, and gender. However, some of these fields may be empty.

I know how to create a query that will check all of those. However, how can I make it where it won't query for something if it's not given. For example, a user might want to search by last name and gender, but not the others.

How can I go about doing this? Thanks so much for the help!

@Ibu, this is what I have so far:

```
// Now we need to query the database for these terms
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `first_name` = '" . $first_name . "' AND `last_name` = '" . $last_name . "' AND `nick_name` = '" . $nick_name . "' AND `grade` = '" . $grade . "' AND `gender` = '" . $gender . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql_query);

// Let's check to make sure there is an actual result
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows < 1) {
    echo 'No student was found using that criteria.';
}

if($num_rows >= 1) {
    echo '<p>' . $num_rows . ' result(s) found. Below are the results:</p>';
    echo '<br />';
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '
        <table border="1" width="400">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">Student Profile - ' . $row['last_name'] . ', ' . $row['first_name'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name: </td>
            <td>' . $row['first_name'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name: </td>
            <td>' . $row['last_name'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nick Name: </td>
            <td>' . $row['nick_name'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Grade: </td>
            <td>' . $row['grade'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gender: </td>
            <td>' . $row['gender'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        </table> <br /><br />';

}
```

Comment: show us the query you have so far

Comment: you wont get any results with the query you have now (if anything is left empty)

Comment: @Neal, yes I know, that's why I'm asking what to do here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the `$_POST` vars and build the query on that.

Like this for example (this bad in that it does not sanitize the `$_POST` for injection, but its a good start):

```
$whereSet = false;
$where = '';
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $whereSet = true;
    $where .= "WHERE name = '{$_POST['name']}'\n";
}
if(isset($_POST['nick'])){
    if(!$whereSet){
        $where .= "WHERE ";
        $whereSet = true;
    }
    else {
        $where .= "AND ";
    }
    $where .= "nick = '{$_POST['nick']}'\n";
}
//...etc
```

Then just append the `$where` variable to the end of your query

Comment: this is extremely prone to sql injection!

Answer (score 2):

Erland Sommarskog is a de-facto source on this quesion:
http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#conclusion

I would write each parameterized `AND` in a format like this:

```
...AND ((@Param IS NULL)  OR (@Param = your_column))
```

Comment: Best choice - although it's popular to hack together some kind of dynamic SQL statement, maybe with "1 = 1" to avoid having to decide where to insert " AND " clauses. This explicitly and completely declares the intended query.

Comment: @le dorfier it does, however, potentially slow down execution depending how how you have your RDBMS set up. @Joe's link is also great for building dynamic SQL (which won't cache plans)

Comment: There is also the more terse version `(@Param = your_column) IS NOT FALSE`

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus but if `@Param IS NULL` then it will fail equality on *everything* ... I've never seen it written like you have there.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to build the SQL query dynamically. Read Gail Shaw's blog post on [Catch-all queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/).

Comment: +1 @Joe It's funny how whenever there's a repeat question on this topic you post Gail Shaw and I post Erland Sommarskog (both are fantastic)

Comment: @Matthew PK: We all have our favorites. :-) Agree that both are excellent. In fact, Gail cites Erland's work in her post. I think I prefer Gail's because it's a bit more concise and easier to follow. Erland's exhaustive, which can sometimes be exhausting.

Comment: and Erland can't be bothered to implement a web layout.

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer creating "clean" queries, by dynamically building the WHERE clause.
Provided that you properly sanitized the data from `$_POST` and copied it into `$data`, with keys in `$data` named after the fields they will be used to filter:

```
$sql = "SELECT ..fields.. FROM ..table..";
$search_enabled_fields = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', /* ..etc.. */);
$conditions = array();
foreach ($search_enabled_fields as $field) {
  if (!empty($data[$field])) { // isset and not an empty string
    $value = $data[$field];
    // maybe you could sanitize $value here if you didn't before..
    $conditions[] = "$field = '$value'";
  }
}
if (count($conditions) > 0) {
  $sql .= " WHERE ". implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}
// now, execute your $sql query..
```

Improving this logic, you could also easily implement different filter types (eg. begins, contains, similar to..) for each field, and build optimized queries for most types of search.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "select * from somewhere where 1 = 1";
if(isset($_POST['something'])){
  $query .= " and something = '{$_POST['something']}'";
}
if(isset($_POST['something_else'])){
  $query .= " and something_else = '{$_POST['something_else']}'";
}
```

etc. but with escaped input

the 1 = 1 is there to avoid having to check if we need to add the "where" keyword